# Stop logging in runtime when running main method

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a project that has a main method in one class that works like a console application. That uses the rest of the code in the project to perform certain tasks.

When running that method I would like to disable the logging; in my case slf4j bound to log4j.

More to the point, the first statements in the main method should disable the logging entirely. An alternative could be to direct the logging to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use this way:

```java
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is equally useful.

Answer (score 0):

### Cancel logging

I found that these two statements at the beginning of your main method performs just that:

```
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.resetConfiguration();
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender());
```

The first removes the current configuration and the second adds a NullAppender that just swallows every logs.

The beauty of it is that running the code in any other fashion (e.g. mvn test) still gives you the logs as expected.

Paul Vargas added an answer with a simpler way to do just this.

### Log redirect

If you still want the logging but directed to a file you can do this:

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(), "log.log"));
```

### Cancel console logging only

Furthermore, if you have a setup with different Appenders where one directs logs to a file you can just do:

```
LogManager.getRootLogger().removeAppender("console");
```

Giving you named your ConsoleAppender 'console'.

### Investigating log4j setup

If you do not know the name of the appender you can run your program with the Java Virtual Machine Argument `-Dlog4j.debug` like this:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dlog4j.debug
```

Then log4j will tell you all you need to know.